# Anyway to output the registration form like the login form with wp_login_form()?

Tags: php, theme-development, user-registration, wp-login-form

I'm trying to create a dual login/register page with WordPress and so far I found out I can create my custom template and then output the login form with [wp_login_form](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_login_form/), however I cannot find any reference to being able to do something similar with the registration form.

I have looked at several articles and none mention anything like that either and many of them just resort to plugins.

Is there a way to achieve this or do I have to go the alternate route of customising the *existing* registration page and seeing if I can output the *login form* on that!?

Answer (score 1):

The registration form is generated by code directly in `wp-login.php` (https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/5.0/src/wp-login.php#L786) and this code is not wrapped with any function, so... I'm afraid there is no such function ready to use.

Of course you can mimic the code from the file above and wrap it with your own function...

Comment: That's pretty annoying. I did think of mimicking the code, but obviously that isn't a very future compatible way of doing things.

Comment: @Brett yes, it is a little bit. On the other hand - that form did not change for few years, so... that’s not as risky as you can think, I guess...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Theme My Login plugin where there  is an option to have a custom registration page on the website.

Theme my login just made a big update. I find that version 6 is better than 7.

Comment: Thanks - but I'm trying to find ways to do it without a plugin if possible.

Comment: A work around would be to embed it on a page in an <iframe> tag